# Who was "a man of G-d" in Divrei Hayamim II 25:7?

Tags: book-of-chronicles

In [Divrei Hayamim II 25:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16574/jewish/Chapter-25.htm) we read how "a man of G-d" came to the king of Judah, Amaziah, to warn him not to take soldiers from Israel with him to the battle against Edomites :

> And a man of G-d came to him, saying, "O king, let not the army of Israel come with you, for the Lord is not with Israel, even with all the sons of Ephraim.

Who was this man of G-d?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Radak [there](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Chronicles.25.7?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_II_Chronicles.25.7.1&lang2=bi) says:

> **ואיש האלהים בא אליו.** אמרו כי זה היה אמוץ אבי ישעיה הנביא
>
> It was said that this was Amoz the father of Isaiah the Prophet

The Medrash ([Sifrei Devarim 342:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.342?lang=bi)) is of this opinion as well.

Comment: A Midrash also says Amoz and Amazia were brothers

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)

Comment: @DanWeisberg of course! Happy to be of help!